# Connection problem when trying to play Steep online

Tags: technical-issues, pc, networking, steep

I have the game Steep which I got while a promotion made it free to install for a limited time and to 
keep it permanently.

I have played other games online without any problems including on Steam and Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege which is from Ubisoft's Uplay launcher, the same as Steep.

When I play Steep and go to the options menu in the social tab the multiplayer icon is red.

[image: Multiplayer group menu]

If I try to connect to a friend to play with them I get the error:

> JOIN HAS FAILED
>
> Cannot connect to the session. There might be a problem with the
>   connection or the player cannot be joined. Please try again later.
>
> [NE-0002]

[image: Error when attempting to join a friend]

They can't join me either but they can spectate.

When I use a free limited VPN ([Windscribe](https://windscribe.com/) in my case, which I tried after watching a YouTube video while trying to find a solution) the problem gets solved and we can play together but I would like to avoid having to use a VPN as it makes the connection slower and because of [other disadvantages](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-US/Faqs/000027273).

Having described my situation I ask if anyone can help me figure out what's most likely the problem and how to solve it as the Ubisoft support pages [connectivity issues in Steep on PC](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-US/Faqs/000025522) and [connectivity troubleshooting](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-US/Faqs/000025515) are a little too broad, extensive and technical (to catch almost any situation people might have) for me to want to try every option and probably do some things wrong or not know what to do.

I use my home's network, connected by ethernet cable from my router (I turn it off and on almost everyday) to my desktop computer, which usually doesn't give problems like this. It might be some configuration of ports or so, but I don't have experience with that so haven't tried anything.